# Sum of differences in array

Tags: arrays, performance, algorithm, complexity-theory

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this:
Given an array `A` of size `n` and two positive integers `a` and `b`, find the sum `floor(abs(A[i]-A[j])*a/b)` taken over all pairs `(i, j)` where `0 <= i < j < n`.

```
int A[n];
int a, b; // assigned some positive integer values
...
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
        total += abs(A[i]-A[j])*a/b; // want integer division here
    }
}
```

To optimize this a little bit, I sorted the array (`O(nlogn)`) and then didn't use an `abs` function. Also, I cached the value `a[i]` before the inner for loop, so I could just read stuff from `A` sequentially. I was considering precomputing `a/b` and storing that in a float, but the extra casting just makes it slower (especially since I want to take the floor of the result).

I couldn't come up with a solution that was better than `O(n^2)`.

Comment: There is an `O(nlogn)` solution if you don't use `floor()`, I think it will be a bit trickier with it. Are you also interested in the sum without `floor()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a more efficient algorithm. It can be done it in O(n*log n). I don't expect there to be an asymptotically faster way, but I'm far from any idea of a proof.

### Algorithm

First sort the array in O(n*log n) time.

Now, let us look at the terms

```
floor((A[j]-A[i])*a/b) = floor ((A[j]*a - A[i]*a)/b)
```

for `0 <= i < j < n`. For each `0 <= k < n`, write `A[k]*a = q[k]*b + r[k]` with `0 <= r[k] < b`.

For `A[k] >= 0`, we have `q[k] = (A[k]*a)/b` and `r[k] = (A[k]*a)%b` with integer division, for `A[k] < 0`, we have `q[k] = (A[k]*a)/b - 1` and `r[k] = b + (A[k]*a)%b` unless `b` divides `A[k]*a`, in which case we have `q[k] = (A[k]*a)/b` and `r[k] = 0`.

Now we rewrite the terms:

```
floor((A[j]*a - A[i]*a)/b) = floor(q[j] - q[i] + (r[j] - r[i])/b)
                           = q[j] - q[i] + floor((r[j] - r[i])/b)
```

Each `q[k]` appears `k` times with positive sign (for `i = 0, 1, .. , k-1`) and `n-1-k` times with negative sign (for `j = k+1, k+2, ..., n-1`), so its total contribution to the sum is

```
(k - (n-1-k))*q[k] = (2*k+1-n)*q[k]
```

The remainders still have to be accounted for. Now, since `0 <= r[k] < b`, we have

```
-b < r[j] - r[i] < b
```

and `floor((r[j]-r[i])/b)` is 0 when `r[j] >= r[i]` and `-1` when `r[j] < r[i]`. So

```
                            n-1
 ∑ floor((A[j]-A[i])*a/b) =  ∑ (2*k+1-n)*q[k] - inversions(r)
i<j                         k=0
```

where an *inversion* is a pair `(i,j)` of indices with `0 <= i < j < n` and `r[j] < r[i]`.

Calculating the `q[k]` and `r[k]` and summing the `(2*k+1-n)*q[k]` is done in O(n) time.

It remains to efficiently count the inversions of the `r[k]` array.

For each index `0 <= k < n`, let `c(k)` be the number of `i < k` such that `r[k] < r[i]`, i.e. the number of inversions in which `k` appears as the larger index.

Then obviously the number of inversions is `∑ c(k)`.

On the other hand, `c(k)` is the number of elements that are moved behind `r[k]` in a stable sort (stability is important here).

Counting these moves, and hence the inversions of an array is easy to do while merge-sorting it.

Thus the inversions can be counted in O(n*log n) too, giving an overall complexity of O(n*log n).

### Code

A sample implementation with a simple unscientific benchmark (but the difference between the naive quadratic algorithm and the above is so large that an unscientific benchmark is conclusive enough).

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

long long mergesort(int *arr, unsigned elems);
long long merge(int *arr, unsigned elems, int *scratch);
long long nosort(int *arr, unsigned elems, long long a, long long b);
long long withsort(int *arr, unsigned elems, long long a, long long b);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned count = (argc > 1) ? strtoul(argv[1],NULL,0) : 1000;
    srand(time(NULL)+count);
    long long a, b;
    b = 1000 + 9000.0*rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.0);
    a = b/3 + (b-b/3)*1.0*rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0);
    int *arr1, *arr2;
    arr1 = malloc(count*sizeof *arr1);
    arr2 = malloc(count*sizeof *arr2);
    if (!arr1 || !arr2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Allocation failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    unsigned i;
    for(i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        arr1[i] = 20000.0*rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0) - 2000;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        arr2[i] = arr1[i];
    }
    long long res1, res2;
    double start = clock();
    res1 = nosort(arr1,count,a,b);
    double stop = clock();
    printf("Naive:   %lld in %.3fs\n",res1,(stop-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    start = clock();
    res2 = withsort(arr2,count,a,b);
    stop = clock();
    printf("Sorting: %lld in %.3fs\n",res2,(stop-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

long long nosort(int *arr, unsigned elems, long long a, long long b) {
    long long total = 0;
    unsigned i, j;
    long long m;
    for(i = 0; i < elems-1; ++i) {
        m = arr[i];
        for(j = i+1; j < elems; ++j) {
            long long d = (arr[j] < m) ? (m-arr[j]) : (arr[j]-m);
            total += (d*a)/b;
        }
    }
    return total;
}

long long withsort(int *arr, unsigned elems, long long a, long long b) {
    long long total = 0;
    unsigned i;
    mergesort(arr,elems);
    for(i = 0; i < elems; ++i) {
        long long q, r;
        q = (arr[i]*a)/b;
        r = (arr[i]*a)%b;
        if (r < 0) {
            r += b;
            q -= 1;
        }
        total += (2*i+1LL-elems)*q;
        arr[i] = (int)r;
    }
    total -= mergesort(arr,elems);
    return total;
}

long long mergesort(int *arr, unsigned elems) {
    if (elems < 2) return 0;
    int *scratch = malloc((elems + 1)/2*sizeof *scratch);
    if (!scratch) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Alloc failure\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return merge(arr, elems, scratch);
}

long long merge(int *arr, unsigned elems, int *scratch) {
    if (elems < 2) return 0;
    unsigned left = (elems + 1)/2, right = elems-left, i, j, k;
    long long inversions = 0;
    inversions += merge(arr, left, scratch);
    inversions += merge(arr+left,right,scratch);
    if (arr[left] < arr[left-1]) {
        for(i = 0; i < left; ++i) {
            scratch[i] = arr[i];
        }
        i = 0; j = 0; k = 0;
        int *lptr = scratch, *rptr = arr+left;
        while(i < left && j < right) {
            if (rptr[j] < lptr[i]) {
                arr[k++] = rptr[j++];
                inversions += (left-i);
            } else {
                arr[k++] = lptr[i++];
            }
        }
        while(i < left) arr[k++] = lptr[i++];
    }
    return inversions;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I had actually come up with an almost identical O(n*log n) solution after discussing with my friends, but I had not actually implemented it. It was nice to verify that this solution works and to actually see your code.